# Unfortunately app has stopped Android emulator

Tags: adt

I'm new to Android programming. I'm getting crazy with this problem.
I'm trying to create a client/server communication with a simple code from this link:
http://lakjeewa.blogspot.it/2012/03/simple-client-server-application-for.html
when i run the "SimpleClientActivity" app on the emulator, it works, but when i press the button, the message "unfortunately, the app has stopped" appears and the app closes.

the Main.java (Server side) works fine.

What can be the problem?

Thank you everybody in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the LogCat console in Eclipse, or whatever you are using as IDE?

Comment: Yes, i've checked it, but it displays lots of colored writing from various processes and i don't know what can be be the problem. However, if this can help, here is the log.txt https://hotfile.com/dl/232721155/a0b617a/log.txt.html